# WebSockets RFC 6455 Spec - Send Data Error

Tags: php, websocket, bit-manipulation

I'm programming a web socket server in PHP, because I could not find one that supported the RFC 6455 spec. In doing so, I used the [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/trunk/%20phpwebsocket/server.php) code as a base and made it RFC 6455 compatible. At least I did for the receive message part. When ever I try to send a message back to the server I get different messages. I'm sure this is due to my skills at bit masking being ... terrible. So after quite a bit of trial and error I still have this problem, and I have no idea why.

```
  Time                     OpCode Mask Length Data
1>2012-06-25T18:05:58.014Z 1      true 4      Ping
2>2012-06-25T18:06:02.121Z 1      true 5      hello
3 2012-06-25T18:06:02.121Z A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the server.
```

or

```
3 2012-06-25T18:06:02.121Z Unexpected continuation frame.
```

I'm using PHP 5.4.4 on my computer, using the command line interface. `php ws.php` is all I need to do in order to start the web socket server. I then use the `wsClient.html` as my client. Using the latest version of Google Chrome (21.0.1180.4 dev-m) on Windows 8 Preview I'm getting the following message.

You can download the php server and client from my [github repo](https://github.com/Dygear/PHPWebSockets) and play long from there. The problem is in the [WebSockets::send](https://github.com/Dygear/PHPWebSockets/blob/master/ws.php#L200) function.

```
private function send($client, $payload)
{
    $frame = pack('C2a*', 0b10000001, 0b01111111 & strlen($payload), $payload);
    socket_write($client, $frame, strlen($frame));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was using little-endian style and not big-endian style when using the binary syntax. I was doing `0b10000001, 0b01111111` when I should be been doing `0b10000001, 0b11111110`.

Answer (score 0):

That message means the browser is getting a continuation frame (0 for the opcode) rather than a text frame (1 for the opcode). I don't think your pack function is working like you intend. I'm not a PHP expert, but perhaps something more like this is what you intended:

```
$plen = strlen($payload);
$frame = pack('CCa{$plen}', ...
```

Also, your payload length calculation is going to break when the payload is longer than 125 bytes. For payloads of 126 to 65535 bytes, you need to put the length in the third and fourth byte of the header. For paylods from 65536 and longer, you need to put the payload length in the 3rd through 10th byte of the header (the length of the header varies depending on the payload length).

Comment: Nope, my code in that regard works. I changed over to your style to check but my short syntax for the pack format is perfectly valid. I also know about not being able to send messages longer then 125 characters, I'm just trying to get it to send a message in the first place.

Comment: Since you are getting "Unexpected continuation frame." means that the bits on the wire are wrong. My best theory is that the pack() call is not giving the expected behavior. Perhaps you should fire up wireshark (or tcpdump) and see what's actually on the wire.

Comment: I did actually find out what the problem was, and i

Comment: You sort of trailed off there.

Comment: Yeah, chrome for the iPad crashed right there. I was saying that I'll post the answer later today.